# How to save information in a text field for future editing

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I created a form with jetpack compose in android in which I want the information in the various textfields should be saved the way they are inputted after exiting and the user can change the information later.

I have built how it looks and I am able to type in the textfield but not save it.

Comment: Try android persistent storage - https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage. Possible options would be files, shared preference, database, or remote.

Comment: How do I use one of the types of storage with a text field?